# NodeMCU does not boot up when GPIO pin is high

Tags: pins, bootloader, nodemcu

I have a NodeMCU board connected to a door and there is a micro switch that makes one GPIO pin (GPIO15 - D8 in this specific case) go high when the door opens.

My problem is if I lose power while the door is opened, the GPIO15 is fed high at the next boot when power is restored. And it makes the board go to a not responding state. I have to boot it again while the door is closed (pin is low) to bring it back to work. I experienced this while flashing too. I cannot flash while this pin is high (while the door is open).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certain pins of the ESP8266 perform special functions at bootup. GPIO15, when HIGH, makes the ESP8266 boot from an SD card.

You can read more about the special functions of the pins [here](http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ESP8266/GPIOpins/index.html).

The solution? Don't use GPIO 0, 2 or 15 for things that can affect the boot sequence.