# Using ESP8266 Adapter with Temperature/Humidity Sensor

Tags: esp8266, temperature-sensor

Good Day. I am currently following a project where I can send data to my firebase database using an ESP8266-ESP01 wifi module and DHT11 temp/hum sensor.
I am using this adapter to enter the boot mode already with a program. Everything seems fine.
[image: Guide]

When I need to upload a program I am just tweaking the adapter using jumper cables to put the GPIO0 to GND and It works fine. My problem now is I have to use the DHT11 Sensor which is supposed to be connected to GPIO2. I tried to go to bootmode so  I connected DHT11(data) directly to the ESP8266(GPIO2) leaving the slot in the adapter empty in which I cant enter the boot mode for some reason.

But when I plug ESP8266(GPIO2) to the adapter slot, I can enter bootmode. Currently confused on how to tweak the adapter to be able to use the GPI02 to the DHT11. Any tips would really help. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeMCU does not boot up when GPIO pin is high](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36938/nodemcu-does-not-boot-up-when-gpio-pin-is-high)

Comment: it's a little vauge how you're wiring it up, but does it boot with the DHT outside of the adapter?

Comment: Please provide information how you're wiring up the DHT to the ESP. Reviewers please hold a bit with the duplicate votes, the question just needs clarification at the moment.

Comment: @Avamander The question clearly states he's using GPIO2. GPIO2 is one of the "special boot mode" GPIOs as detailed in the duplicate question. What further clarification can you want?

Comment: DHT has four (three different) pins, is he powering it correctly? And would a DHT really pull GPIO2 low for the ESP to not boot properly?

Comment: @Avamander: you mean `LOW` right? regardless, since the data pin uses a `PULLUP`, i don't see how a DHT11 would prevent normal booting as described, if it's wired correctly.

Comment: @dandavis Yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the tips. I have found a way to use the esp8266 adapter with the DHT11 sensor. First of all it was on boot mode all along, I had some code mistakes where my target url includes an 'https' tag on it thus not functioning as expected.

For those who would like to use this specific adapter with DHT11 attached in boot mode.

-Connect all female jumper wires end to the Esp8266 and the male jumper ends to the adapter except for the GPI02.

-The GPI02 slot on the adapter will be empty but the ESP8266 GPI02 end must be connected to the data pin of the DHT11.

Make sure that the ESP8266 and DHT11 sensor have enough power for both devices.

Comment: Accept your own response to close your question.